# Nginx wrong root directory

Tags: nginx, webserver, wildcard, wildcard-subdomain

I have the following server settings, and for some reason, my document root is going to the wrong location. Why is it doing that? `$1` is correct on the `return` line, but why is it pulling the wrong root?

**This block is broken:**

```
server{
    listen 80;

    #server_name mission13.io www.mission13.io;

    server_name "~^www\.(.*)$";
    return 301 $scheme://$1$request_uri;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html/$1;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    include /usr/share/nginx/conf/mission13.io.conf;
    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

**This block works:**

```
server{
    listen 80;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/diskise.com;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name diskise.com www.diskise.com;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    include /usr/share/nginx/conf/diskise.com.conf;
    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

it is using a `root` that is set somewhere else, a completely different file.

Comment: In this server block you redirect everything, so `root` is not used at all. Probably you should show us some other server block.

Comment: @alexeyten I have updated the question, with the whole block and added one that works.